# SWIG and triggering a Python callback from C code

Tags: swig

Apologies for not being familiar with formatting on here...I've made
some progress thanks to helpful replies and edited and removed my original
question to be replaced by the current one.

My problem lies with converting a C struct or struct pointer to PyObject. There
is no alternative to this because I am wrapping an existing C library whose
callback requires a C struct pointer.

Following works but with limitations:

```
%module cain1
%{

  typedef struct {
    double price;
    int volume;
  } book_entry_t;

  typedef struct {

    char symbol[10];
    book_entry_t *book;

  } trade_t;

  typedef void (*CALLBACK)(trade_t trade);

  CALLBACK my_callback = 0;
  static PyObject *my_pycallback = NULL;

  static void bigSnake(trade_t trade)
  {
    PyObject *result;

    PyObject *d1;

    result =  PyEval_CallObject(my_pycallback,

                Py_BuildValue("(y#)",
                          (char*)&trade,
                          sizeof(trade_t)
                          )

                );

    Py_XDECREF(result);
    return /*void*/;

  }

  void test_cb (PyObject *callMe1) {
    trade_t d1;
    book_entry_t b1;
    b1.price = 123.45;
    b1.volume = 99;


    Py_XINCREF(callMe1);         /* Add a reference to new callback */
    my_pycallback = callMe1;     /* Remember new callback */

    strcpy (d1.symbol,"Gupta Ltd");
    d1.book = &b1;


    bigSnake(d1);

  }


%}


// Expose in python module..
typedef struct {
  double price;
  int volume;
} book_entry_t;

typedef struct {

  char symbol[10];
  book_entry_t *book;

} trade_t;


void test_cb(PyObject *callMe1);
```

and then triggering the callback from Python:

```
import cain1
import struct 

def dave(d1):
    N1,N2 = struct.unpack('10sP', d1)
    print ('\n   %s: %x' % (N1.decode() ,N2))

    price,volume = struct.unpack('di',N2)

    print (price,volume)

def main():
    cain1.test_cb(dave) 

main()
```

but I am unable to recover the book_entry_t strcut contents pointed to by trade_t....

I just feel this is all too convoluted since I have the pointer to structs and there
must be a straightforward way for Python to use that without any fuss.

Comment: Where does gdb tell you it's segfaulting?

Answer (score 1):

`Py_BuildValue("(N)",details)` expects a `PyObject*` (your "N" says so), and you pass it something very different. Try `Py_BuildValue("(i)", details.index)` instead, and change it to accomodate any changes in `details_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to build a PyObject from a `details_t` struct. This isn't valid. Either pass the callback an integer (seems easier since `details_t` only has the one field) OR create a proper PyObject type. You can't blindly cast one type to another and expect it to work (a PyObject is more than just a pointer).

Comment: Yes, therein lies the problem. Passing an integer or string etc.

Comment: Yes that is problem. It works fine passing an integer or string,

Comment: Sorry...
Yes works fine with integer, string etc. However I am wrapping
an existing library and the callback requires a pointer to a
C struct. I am puzzling over whether there is a painless way
of converting a C struct to a PyObject without a lot of pain.

    result =  PyEval_CallObject(my_pycallback,
    
    Py_BuildValue("(y#)",
           (char*)&trade,
           sizeof(trade_t)
           )
    
    );

works where 
  typedef struct {

    char symbol[10];
    book_entry_t *book;
   
  } trade_t;